# Flattening a 3 level nested JSON string in java

Tags: java, json, jackson

The requirement is to create a generic flattening utility for an input JSON object to a flattened JSON object.

The sample JSON looks like the below

```
{
  "Source": "source-1",
  "Rows": [
    {
      "Keys": {
        "device-id": "BC04-EBH-N3K-01",
        "interface-name": "TenGigE0/0/0/39",
        "node-name": "0/0/CPU0"
      },
      "Timestamp": 1567621527656,
      "inner": {
        "donm": {
          "id": "0062",
          "mol": {
            "rem": 30,
            "len": 11,
            "org": {
              "ldp": [
                {
                  "t": 486,
                  "o": 322
                },
                {
                  "t": 487,
                  "o": 32,
                  "twss": 1,
                  "tlv": "00:01"
                }
              ]
            },
            "chlen": 14,
            "poe": 5,
            "combs": 10,
            "chaype": 4,
            "rek": 0,
            "rem-um": 67
          },
          "detail": {
            "enas": "B,R",
            "systes": "B,R",
            "timng": 91,
            "syn": "C",
            "met-type": 0,
            "neses": {
              "lldEDIT": [
                {
                  "ium": 830,
                  "m": 1,
                  "ass": {
                    "ape": "ipv4",
                    "ipvs": "94"
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            "pess": "0008",
            "por]d": 0,
            "pon": "BCtive",
            "sysme": "BC1"
          },
          "reme": "Bu1",
          "hean": 0,
          "porl": "Et1"
        }
      }
    }

  ],
  "Tey": {
    "epath": "Cgetail",
    "sustr": "MX",
    "coime": 1567621527653,
    "msp": 1567621527653,
    "come": 1567621527660,
    "nor": "BC5",
    "cid": 14789654
  }
}
```

I have been trying to flatten it to 3 levels and came up with the below utility. But, The things are getting complicated when I have to deal with Arrays and values of type String, long, Timestamp, etc. Also, I am unable to understand how the nested keys can be maintained for uniqueness.

```
public static Map<String,Object> flattenJson(JsonNode input){
        Map<String,Object> finalMap = new HashMap<>();

        ObjectMapper datamapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String,Object> topLevelJsonMap = datamapper.convertValue(input,Map.class);
        Set<String> topLevelKeys = topLevelJsonMap.keySet();

        for(String topLevelKey : topLevelKeys){

            System.out.println("Key :::: "+topLevelKey);

            Object topLevelData = topLevelJsonMap.get(topLevelKey);
            System.out.println("value :::: "+topLevelData.toString());

            if(topLevelData instanceof ArrayNode){
                ArrayNode arrayOfData = (ArrayNode) topLevelData;
                for(JsonNode dataNode : arrayOfData){
                    flattenJson(input);
                }
            } else if(topLevelData instanceof JsonNode){
                Map<String,Object> innerLevelJsonMap = datamapper.convertValue(topLevelData,Map.class);
                Set<String> innerLevelKeys = innerLevelJsonMap.keySet();
                for(String innerLevelKey : innerLevelKeys){
                    System.out.println("inner key :::: "+innerLevelKey);
                    flattenJson((JsonNode) innerLevelJsonMap.get(innerLevelKey));
                }
            }else {
               finalMap.put(topLevelKey,topLevelData);
            }
        }
        return finalMap;
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid conflicts with key names you can use [JSON Pointer](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-appsawg-json-pointer-03) specification to create them. It is also supported by `Jackson` library, so you can use them later to traverse the `JsonNode` node.

Simple implementation could look like below:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class JsonApp {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File jsonFile = new File("./test.json");

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(jsonFile);
    Map<String, JsonNode> map = new JsonFlattener(root).flatten();

    System.out.println("Use key-value pairs:");
    map.forEach(
        (k, v) -> {
          System.out.println(k + " => " + v);
        });

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Use pointers:");
    map.forEach(
        (k, v) -> {
          System.out.println(k + " => " + root.at(k));
        });
  }
}

class JsonFlattener {

  private final Map<String, JsonNode> json = new LinkedHashMap<>(64);
  private final JsonNode root;

  JsonFlattener(JsonNode node) {
    this.root = Objects.requireNonNull(node);
  }

  public Map<String, JsonNode> flatten() {
    process(root, "");
    return json;
  }

  private void process(JsonNode node, String prefix) {
    if (node.isObject()) {
      ObjectNode object = (ObjectNode) node;
      object
          .fields()
          .forEachRemaining(
              entry -> {
                  process(entry.getValue(), prefix + "/" + entry.getKey());
              });
    } else if (node.isArray()) {
      ArrayNode array = (ArrayNode) node;
      AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
      array
          .elements()
          .forEachRemaining(
              item -> {
                process(item, prefix + "/" + counter.getAndIncrement());
              });
    } else {
      json.put(prefix, node);
    }
  }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
Use key-value pairs:
/Source => "source-1"
/Rows/0/Keys/device-id => "BC04-EBH-N3K-01"
/Rows/0/Keys/interface-name => "TenGigE0/0/0/39"
/Rows/0/Keys/node-name => "0/0/CPU0"
/Rows/0/Timestamp => 1567621527656
/Rows/0/inner/donm/id => "0062"
/Rows/0/inner/donm/mol/rem => 30
/Rows/0/inner/donm/mol/len => 11
/Rows/0/inner/donm/mol/org/ldp/0/t => 486
/Rows/0/inner/donm/mol/org/ldp/0/o => 322
/Rows/0/inner/donm/mol/org/ldp/1/t => 487
/Rows/0/inner/donm/mol/org/ldp/1/o => 32
/Rows/0/inner/donm/mol/org/ldp/1/twss => 1
/Rows/0/inner/donm/mol/org/ldp/1/tlv => "00:01"
/Rows/0/inner/donm/mol/chlen => 14
/Rows/0/inner/donm/mol/poe => 5
/Rows/0/inner/donm/mol/combs => 10
/Rows/0/inner/donm/mol/chaype => 4
/Rows/0/inner/donm/mol/rek => 0
/Rows/0/inner/donm/mol/rem-um => 67
/Rows/0/inner/donm/detail/enas => "B,R"
/Rows/0/inner/donm/detail/systes => "B,R"
/Rows/0/inner/donm/detail/timng => 91
/Rows/0/inner/donm/detail/syn => "C"
/Rows/0/inner/donm/detail/met-type => 0
/Rows/0/inner/donm/detail/neses/lldEDIT/0/ium => 830
/Rows/0/inner/donm/detail/neses/lldEDIT/0/m => 1
/Rows/0/inner/donm/detail/neses/lldEDIT/0/ass/ape => "ipv4"
/Rows/0/inner/donm/detail/neses/lldEDIT/0/ass/ipvs => "94"
/Rows/0/inner/donm/detail/pess => "0008"
/Rows/0/inner/donm/detail/por]d => 0
/Rows/0/inner/donm/detail/pon => "BCtive"
/Rows/0/inner/donm/detail/sysme => "BC1"
/Rows/0/inner/donm/reme => "Bu1"
/Rows/0/inner/donm/hean => 0
/Rows/0/inner/donm/porl => "Et1"
/Tey/epath => "Cgetail"
/Tey/sustr => "MX"
/Tey/coime => 1567621527653
/Tey/msp => 1567621527653
/Tey/come => 1567621527660
/Tey/nor => "BC5"
/Tey/cid => 14789654

Use pointers:
/Source => "source-1"
/Rows/0/Keys/device-id => "BC04-EBH-N3K-01"
/Rows/0/Keys/interface-name => "TenGigE0/0/0/39"
/Rows/0/Keys/node-name => "0/0/CPU0"
/Rows/0/Timestamp => 1567621527656
/Rows/0/inner/donm/id => "0062"
/Rows/0/inner/donm/mol/rem => 30
/Rows/0/inner/donm/mol/len => 11
/Rows/0/inner/donm/mol/org/ldp/0/t => 486
/Rows/0/inner/donm/mol/org/ldp/0/o => 322
/Rows/0/inner/donm/mol/org/ldp/1/t => 487
/Rows/0/inner/donm/mol/org/ldp/1/o => 32
/Rows/0/inner/donm/mol/org/ldp/1/twss => 1
/Rows/0/inner/donm/mol/org/ldp/1/tlv => "00:01"
/Rows/0/inner/donm/mol/chlen => 14
/Rows/0/inner/donm/mol/poe => 5
/Rows/0/inner/donm/mol/combs => 10
/Rows/0/inner/donm/mol/chaype => 4
/Rows/0/inner/donm/mol/rek => 0
/Rows/0/inner/donm/mol/rem-um => 67
/Rows/0/inner/donm/detail/enas => "B,R"
/Rows/0/inner/donm/detail/systes => "B,R"
/Rows/0/inner/donm/detail/timng => 91
/Rows/0/inner/donm/detail/syn => "C"
/Rows/0/inner/donm/detail/met-type => 0
/Rows/0/inner/donm/detail/neses/lldEDIT/0/ium => 830
/Rows/0/inner/donm/detail/neses/lldEDIT/0/m => 1
/Rows/0/inner/donm/detail/neses/lldEDIT/0/ass/ape => "ipv4"
/Rows/0/inner/donm/detail/neses/lldEDIT/0/ass/ipvs => "94"
/Rows/0/inner/donm/detail/pess => "0008"
/Rows/0/inner/donm/detail/por]d => 0
/Rows/0/inner/donm/detail/pon => "BCtive"
/Rows/0/inner/donm/detail/sysme => "BC1"
/Rows/0/inner/donm/reme => "Bu1"
/Rows/0/inner/donm/hean => 0
/Rows/0/inner/donm/porl => "Et1"
/Tey/epath => "Cgetail"
/Tey/sustr => "MX"
/Tey/coime => 1567621527653
/Tey/msp => 1567621527653
/Tey/come => 1567621527660
/Tey/nor => "BC5"
/Tey/cid => 14789654
```

Answer (score 6):

You can take a look on [json-flattener](https://github.com/wnameless/json-flattener).

BTW, I am the author of this lib.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
public static void flattenJson(JsonNode node, String parent, Map<String, ValueNode> map) {
    if (node instanceof ValueNode) {
        map.put(parent, (ValueNode)node);
    } else {
        String prefix = parent == null ? "" : parent + ".";
        if (node instanceof ArrayNode) {
            ArrayNode arrayNode = (ArrayNode)node;
            for(int i = 0; i < arrayNode.size(); i++) {
                flattenJson(arrayNode.get(i), prefix + i, map);
            }
        } else if (node instanceof ObjectNode) {
            ObjectNode objectNode = (ObjectNode) node;
            for (Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> it = objectNode.fields(); it.hasNext(); ) {
                Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> field = it.next();
                flattenJson(field.getValue(), prefix + field.getKey(), map);
            }
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("unknown json node");
        }
    }
}

public static Map<String, ValueNode> flattenJson(JsonNode input) {
    Map<String, ValueNode> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    flattenJson(input, null, map);
    return map;
}
```

Then you can call

```
    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode jsonNode = om.readTree(json);
    Map<String, ValueNode> m = flattenJson(jsonNode);
    for (Map.Entry<String, ValueNode> kv : m.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(kv.getKey() + "=" + kv.getValue().asText());
    }
```

Output:

```
Source=source-1
Rows.0.Keys.device-id=BC04-EBH-N3K-01
Rows.0.Keys.interface-name=TenGigE0/0/0/39
Rows.0.Keys.node-name=0/0/CPU0
Rows.0.Timestamp=1567621527656
Rows.0.inner.donm.id=0062
Rows.0.inner.donm.mol.rem=30
Rows.0.inner.donm.mol.len=11
Rows.0.inner.donm.mol.org.ldp.0.t=486
Rows.0.inner.donm.mol.org.ldp.0.o=322
Rows.0.inner.donm.mol.org.ldp.1.t=487
Rows.0.inner.donm.mol.org.ldp.1.o=32
Rows.0.inner.donm.mol.org.ldp.1.twss=1
Rows.0.inner.donm.mol.org.ldp.1.tlv=00:01
Rows.0.inner.donm.mol.chlen=14
Rows.0.inner.donm.mol.poe=5
Rows.0.inner.donm.mol.combs=10
Rows.0.inner.donm.mol.chaype=4
Rows.0.inner.donm.mol.rek=0
Rows.0.inner.donm.mol.rem-um=67
Rows.0.inner.donm.detail.enas=B,R
Rows.0.inner.donm.detail.systes=B,R
Rows.0.inner.donm.detail.timng=91
Rows.0.inner.donm.detail.syn=C
Rows.0.inner.donm.detail.met-type=0
Rows.0.inner.donm.detail.neses.lldEDIT.0.ium=830
Rows.0.inner.donm.detail.neses.lldEDIT.0.m=1
Rows.0.inner.donm.detail.neses.lldEDIT.0.ass.ape=ipv4
Rows.0.inner.donm.detail.neses.lldEDIT.0.ass.ipvs=94
Rows.0.inner.donm.detail.pess=0008
Rows.0.inner.donm.detail.por]d=0
Rows.0.inner.donm.detail.pon=BCtive
Rows.0.inner.donm.detail.sysme=BC1
Rows.0.inner.donm.reme=Bu1
Rows.0.inner.donm.hean=0
Rows.0.inner.donm.porl=Et1
Tey.epath=Cgetail
Tey.sustr=MX
Tey.coime=1567621527653
Tey.msp=1567621527653
Tey.come=1567621527660
Tey.nor=BC5
Tey.cid=14789654
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create namespace of the keys by appending each level key into the key from higher level.
In other words your flattened JSON's keys would be:

```
{
 "L1key::L2key": "L2val",
 "L1key": "L1val",
 "L1key::L2key::L3key": "L3val"
}
```

This way you guarantee uniqueness but also you can create the original json from this as well. Lastly be sure that the level separator (here `::`) will not be present in your key.

HTH