# Is there a way to compare keys of two property files with different structure?

Tags: json, properties-file

I have two +10.000 lines property files with diferent structure and I need to know which keys are in both files.

I tryed using tools as WinMerge and FileMerge with out any luck.

File1:

```
.
.
.
  "CardShipmentScale.shipmentScaleRegional": "SomeText1",
  "CardShipmentScale.shipmentScaleRegionalExplanation": "SomeText2",
  "CheckboxCard.DAY": "SomeText3",
  "CheckboxCard.MONTH": "SomeText4",
  "SomeOtherKey.SomeOtherSubKey": "SomeOtherText5"
.
.
.
```

File2:

```
{ "global" : {
.
.
.
      CardShipmentScale : {
          shipmentScaleRegional : "SomeText1",
          shipmentScaleRegionalExplanation : "SomeText2"
                          },
      SomeOtherKey : {
          SomeOtherSubKey : "SomeOtherText5"
                     },

.
.
.

}
```

In this example, I would like to have a tool o report that indicates that  `CardShipmentScale` was found in file1 and file2, but `CheckboxCard` only in file1.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the format of `File1` and `File2`? `File1` does not look like a valid properties file and `File2` like a valid `JSON` file. Is `global` node contains all sub nodes and it is a root in a file? Which language you want to use?

Comment: Michal thanks for your commet, File1 and File2 are both valid Json files, in File2 global contain all sub nodes yes.

Comment: About language, I’m happy with any one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start from this answer [Flattening a 3 level nested JSON string in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58008267/flattening-a-3-level-nested-json-string-in-java/58009049#58009049). I created there `JsonFlattener` which converts `JSON` file to `Map` where key is a `JSON Path`.

Now it should be easy to check every key from first file in second file:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.Annotated;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class JsonPathApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile0 = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();
        File jsonFile1 = new File("./resource/test1.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, JsonNode> map0 = new JsonFlattener(mapper.readTree(jsonFile0)).flatten();
        Map<String, JsonNode> map1 = new JsonFlattener(mapper.readTree(jsonFile1)).flatten();

        for (Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> node : map0.entrySet()) {
            String keyToCheck = "/global" + node.getKey().replace('.', '/');
            if (map1.containsKey(keyToCheck)) {
                System.out.println(node.getKey() + " exists in both files.");
            } else {
                System.out.println(node.getKey() + " exists only in 1 file.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`test.json` contains:

```
{
  "CardShipmentScale.shipmentScaleRegional": "SomeText1",
  "CardShipmentScale.shipmentScaleRegionalExplanation": "SomeText2",
  "CheckboxCard.DAY": "SomeText3",
  "CheckboxCard.MONTH": "SomeText4",
  "SomeOtherKey.SomeOtherSubKey": "SomeOtherText5"
}
```

`test1.json` contains:

```
{
  "global": {
    "CardShipmentScale": {
      "shipmentScaleRegional": "SomeText1",
      "shipmentScaleRegionalExplanation": "SomeText2"
    },
    "SomeOtherKey": {
      "SomeOtherSubKey": "SomeOtherText5"
    }
  }
}
```

For above files app prints:

```
/CardShipmentScale.shipmentScaleRegional exists in both files.
/CardShipmentScale.shipmentScaleRegionalExplanation exists in both files.
/CheckboxCard.DAY exists only in 1 file.
/CheckboxCard.MONTH exists only in 1 file.
/SomeOtherKey.SomeOtherSubKey exists in both files.
```

Comment: This is working, I just changed two lines:
Map<String, Object> map0 = new JsonFlattener(mapper.readTree(jsonFile0).toString()).flattenAsMap();
        Map<String, Object> map1 = new JsonFlattener(mapper.readTree(jsonFile1).toString()).flattenAsMap();


thanks a lot