# Parsing nested Json to table (with all permutations for nested attribute)

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson, jsonparser

I have data in JSON format:

```
{
   "orders":[
      {
         "id":"1",
         "price":720,
         "customers":[
            {
               "id":"10",
               "name":"customer A" 
            },
            {
               "id":"14",
               "name": "customer B"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":"2",
         "price":68,
         "customers":[
            {
               "id":"7",
               "name":"customer X"
            },
            {
               "id":"8",
               "name":"customer Y"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

My task is go throught these data and create table with columns like for example `orders.id`, `orders.number`, `orders.customers.id` and so on (and of course with data from right side) and with all permutations for nested objects.

So in this case I should got something like:

```
+-----------+--------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
| orders.id | orders.price | orders.customers.id | orders.customers.name |
+-----------+--------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
|         1 |          720 |                  10 | customer A            |
|         1 |          720 |                  14 | customer B            |
|         2 |           68 |                   7 | customer X            |
|         2 |           68 |                   8 | customer Y            |
+-----------+--------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
```

The main problem is that I don't know the structure of this file when loading it. So I don't know the type, name and number of attributes and nesting level. I don't know what classes I should keep data in.

I tried use this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58009049/11846473
to flatten my Json, but I'm not sure if this is good idea...

I would like use Jaskson library to do this. Could you give me some hints?

Comment: Why exactly can't you use the code you've referenced?

Comment: Because these code only flattern Json. I can not then make permutations and I'm loosing information about nested nodes (which one belongs to parent? How many elements has?). Eventually I can parse names of nodes in output but in my opinion that is not good idea...Maybe you can show how can I use code from flattering Json?

Comment: Can you maybe be more specific about your input json? Where does it come from? Do you only have to display it in a fancy table? Etc.

Comment: I am getting this Json as ```byte[]``` so I am reading it as 
```ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();```
```JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(file);```
I need to store my results in ```List<Row>``` where every Row is simple ```Map<String, String>```. As key is comma separeted column names and value is coma separeted values so in my case for example (for first row):
```<"orders.id, orders.price, orders.customers.id, orders.customers.name", "1, 720, 10, customer A" >```