# Recursively flatten a map of nested objects

Tags: java, json, recursion, jackson

I have a list of map of fields from ElasticSearch in a JSON structure. I need to extract the keys from the fields into a `name.value` list to be used as search terms.

For example, the response I get from ElasticSearch looks like:

```json
{
    "orange": {
        "type": "keyword"
    },
    "apple": {
        "type": "keyword"
    },
    "banana": {
        "type": "keyword"
    },
    "pineapple": {
        "properties": {
            "color": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "size": {
                "type": "text"
            }
        }
    },
    "vegetables": {
        "properties": {
            "potato": {
                "properties": {
                    "quality": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "price": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "location": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to transform this into a list of

```json
[
  "orange",
  "apple",
  "banana",
  "pineapple.color",
  "pineapple.size",
  "vegetables.potato.quality",
  "vegetables.potato.price",
  "vegetables.potato.location",
  "vegetables.cabbage"
]
```

I'm a bit lost as to where to start so I end up with something that will work no matter how deep the "object" + "properties" key ends up being.

**edit:**

I have a couple of methods I'm trying to do this with, but I keep ending up with nested loops instead

```java
private static String process(final Map.Entry<String, Object> entry) {
    final String fieldName = entry.getKey();
    final Map<String, Object> value = toSourceMap(entry.getValue());
    if (value.containsKey("properties")) {
        final Map<String, Object> properties = toSourceMap(value.get("properties"));
        process(entry); // ??
    }
    return fieldName;
}
```

And a small helper method I'm using which casts the unknown object to a map

```java
private static Map<String, Object> toSourceMap(final Object sourceMap) {
    try {
        final Map<String, Object> map = (Map) sourceMap;
        return map;
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        return Map.of();
    }
}
```

And I'm calling this

```java
final List<String> fieldName = new ArrayList<>();

for (final Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : properties.entrySet()) {
    fieldName.add(process(entry));
}
```

Trying to get a list of each value from the `process` method

**edit 2:**
I can get something that works for one level deep, but this won't capture the deeper objects like `vegetables.potato.quality`

```java
    private static List<String> process(final Map.Entry<String, Object> entry) {

        final String fieldName = entry.getKey();
        final Map<String, Object> value = toSourceMap(entry.getValue());

        final List<String> fields = new ArrayList<>();
        if (value.containsKey("properties")) {
            final Map<String, Object> properties = toSourceMap(value.get("properties"));

            properties.keySet().stream().map(s -> fieldName + "." + s).forEach(fields::add);
        } else {
            fields.add(fieldName);
        }

        return fields;
    }
```

and the caller

```java
        final List<String> fieldName = new ArrayList<>();

        for (final Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : properties.entrySet()) {
            fieldName.addAll(process(entry));
        }
```

Comment: In this case dialing with a Map is cumbersome, what json-library you're using in your project?

Comment: I have access to Jackson if that's easier?

Comment: One more clarification: why `properties` attribute-name was discarded here `""vegetables.potato.quality"` (not `"vegetables.properties.potato.properties.quality"`) ?

Comment: `Properties` is like a root object which holds values and not something thats needed when sending search queries to elasticsearch

Comment: You can take a loon on the similar question [Flattening a 3 level nested JSON string in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58008267/flattening-a-3-level-nested-json-string-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure theres a cleaner and better way to do it, but I was able to achieve what I needed by doing the following

```java
   private static List<String> process(final Map.Entry<String, Object> entry) {

    final String fieldName = entry.getKey();
    final List<String> fields = new ArrayList<>();
    final Map<String, Object> value = toSourceMap(entry.getValue());

    if (value.containsKey(MAPPING_PROPERTIES)) {
        toSourceMap(value.get(MAPPING_PROPERTIES)).entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(FieldMappingFactory::process)
            .map(nestedFields -> nestedFields.stream().map(f -> "%s.%s".formatted(fieldName, f)).toList())
            .forEach(fields::addAll);
    } else {
        fields.add(fieldName);
    }

    return fields;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution based on the [*Depth first search*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) tree-traversal algorithm.

Since it's **iterative**, you can use it to process even deeply nested massive JSON without a risk of getting a `StackOverFlowError`.

To implement DFS, we need a Stack and a Map is needed to store the paths associated with a node that are being explored.

As the first step, we need to read the whole JSON tree and the obtained `JsonNode` on the stack.

Then, until the stack is not empty, need to examine each node it contains by pulling them out from the stack. If the node happens to be an `ArrayNode` or `ObjectNode`, then all its children-nodes which could be obtained via [`JsonNode.fields()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#fields()) should be added on the stack.

```
String json = // the source JSON
JsonNode node = new ObjectMapper().readTree(json);
    
List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
Deque<JsonNode> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
        
Map<JsonNode, List<String>> pathByNode = new HashMap<>();
pathByNode.put(node, Collections.emptyList());
        
Set<String> keysToExclude = Set.of("type", "properties"); // add more if you need
        
stack.push(node);
        
while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
    JsonNode current = stack.pop();
    List<String> path = pathByNode.get(current);
            
    if (current instanceof ArrayNode || current instanceof ObjectNode) {
                
        for (Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> it = current.fields(); it.hasNext(); ) {
                    
            Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> next = it.next();
            stack.push(next.getValue());
    
            String propertyName = next.getKey();
            List<String> newPath;
                    
            if (!keysToExclude.contains(propertyName)) {
                newPath = new ArrayList<>(path);
                newPath.add(propertyName);
    
                results.add(String.join(".", newPath)); // list of path should be updated
            } else {
                newPath = path;
            }
            pathByNode.put(next.getValue(), newPath);
        }
    }
}
        
results.forEach(System.out::println);
```

*Output:*

```
orange
apple
banana
pineapple
vegetables
vegetables.potato
vegetables.potato.quality
vegetables.potato.price
vegetables.potato.location
pineapple.color
pineapple.size
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simpler solution.

```
private static void process(List<String> paths, String path, JsonNode node, Set<String> excludeKeys) {
    if (node.isValueNode()) {
        paths.add(path);
    } else if (node.isObject()) {
        node.fields().forEachRemaining(elem -> {
            String key = excludeKeys.contains(elem.getKey()) ? path : (path == null ? "" : path + ".") + elem.getKey();
            process(paths, key, elem.getValue(), excludeKeys);
        });
    } else { // This part is not required if there is no array inside the source JSON object
        for (int i = 0; i < node.size(); i++) {
            process(paths, String.format("%s[%d]", path, i), node.get(i), excludeKeys);
        }
    }
}
```

Caller

```
JsonNode node = new ObjectMapper().readTree(// JSON string //);
List<String> paths = new ArrayList<>();
process(paths, null, node, Set.of("properties", "type"));
paths.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output

```
orange
apple
banana
pineapple.color
pineapple.size
vegetables.potato.quality
vegetables.potato.price
vegetables.potato.location
```